# How to show how much time elapsed in Codelite?

Tags: optimization, time, codelite

So I have been coding on codelite and now want to optimize it, however for some reason it doesn't show me how much time elapsed. It just shows me the output and then "Press any key to continue.." and that's it.
I haven't found anything online regarding that, seems like I am the only one with that problem.
So how do I enable it back so I can keep track of how much time it takes my code to compile so I may optimize it?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question specifically, but compile time says nothing about how optimized your application is :)

Comment: I thought the less time it takes, the more optimized it is. How isn't it so? Sorry, I am a beginner to all this.